# Basic idea of Quaternion y axis 90 degree rotate

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I want to rotate the object around y axis 90　degree.

What I want to do is very simple

```
    getPosition(Quaternion rotation)
        rotation.y = rotation.y + 90.0f;
        _rotateTarget.rotation = rotation;
```

it shows error.

I googled around and found I need to understand `Quaternion`

However I can't find first clue to rotate object simply 90 degree.

Is there any help??

Comment: I don't think unity explicitly allows you to set the x,y,z of quaternions, have you tried creating a new quaternion with Quaternion Euler(float x, float y, float z);  and adding 90 to the y parameter?

Answer (score 3):

A [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) has not three but rather **four** components `x`, `y`, `z` **and `w`**! And they all move in the range `-1` to `1`.

=> **Never** touch the individual components of a `Quaternion` except you really know exactly what you are doing!

---

For rotating the object on the global Y-axis you rather want to use e.g. [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) as the name suggests generates a `Quaternion` rotation from the given Euler space angles.

> Returns a rotation that rotates z degrees around the z axis, x degrees around the x axis, and y degrees around the y axis; applied in that order.

```c#
rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);
// Or also
//rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.up * 90);
_rotateTarget.rotation = rotation;
```

Or if you want to rotate in any given axis you can also use [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html)

```c#
rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(90, Vector3.up);
_rotateTarget.rotation = rotation;
```

And then you always combine two `Quaternion` using the [multiplication `*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html).

```c#
var final = rotA * rotB;
```

basically means first apply the rotation `rotA` then starting from there additionally apply the `rotB`.

```c#
rotation *= rotB;
```

is just a shorthand for writing

```c#
rotation = rotation * rotB;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate an object smoothly to a target rotation you can use `Quaternion.Slerp`. The following script lets you set the x, y and z rotation.

```
[Header("Settings")]
public Vector3 targetRotation;
public float rotationSpeed = 5;

private Quaternion currentTargetRotation;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Update()
{
    if (currentTargetRotation.eulerAngles != targetRotation)
        currentTargetRotation.eulerAngles = targetRotation;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, currentTargetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Cool and all .. but has nothing to do with the question ;) The question is about how to get the target rotation in the first place ..  not if we then rotate there smooth or hard ;)

Comment: @derHugo and also the Slerp function can't be used like that

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya yes it can (why do you think that not?), it just doesn't seem to be what OP asked for.